# VueJS - Pass slot to child of child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a list and a list_item component that I reuse a lot inside my application. On a simplified form:

**contact_list.vue**

```
<template lang="pug">
    .table  
      .table-header.table-row
        .table-col Contact
        .table-col Info

      .table-body
          contact-list-item(v-for='contact in contacts',
                            :contact='contact',
                            @click='doSomething()')

</template>
```

**contact_list_item.vue**

```
<template lang="pug">
.table-row(@click='emitClickEvent')
  .table-col {{ contact.name }}
  .table-col {{ contact.info }}
</template>
```

When I use contact_list inside a specific component, I want to be able to send a slot that will add some new columns to the contact_list_item component. This slot will use data of the specific contact that is being rendered inside that contact_list_item component to generate the new columns.

How could I achieve that? Is using slot the best approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Slots are the best approach and you will need to use a scoped slot for the `contact-list-item` component. I'm not really familiar with pug, so I will use HTML for the example.

In `contact-list` you would add a slot. Notice in this case that the contact is being passed as a property. This is so we can take advantage of [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots).

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-header table-row">  
    <div class="table-col">Contact</div>
    <div class="table-col">Info</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-body">
    <contact-list-item v-for='contact in contacts'
                       :contact="contact"
                       @click="doSomething"
                       :key="contact.id">
      <slot :contact="contact"></slot>
    </contact-list-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add a slot to the `contact-list-item`.

```
<div class="table-row" @click="emitClickEvent">
  <div class="table-col">{{contact.name}}</div>
  <div class="table-col">{{contact.info}}</div>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

Finally, in your Vue template, use the scoped template.

```
<div id="app">
  <contact-list :contacts="contacts">
    <template scope="{contact}">
      <div class="table-col">{{contact.id}}</div>
    </template>
  </contact-list>
</div>
```

Here is a [working example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/awGmjj?editors=1010). I have no idea what your styles are but notice the `id` column is now displayed in the `contact-list-item`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `template` for registering slot to the child of child component.

There is also a case when you want to have many named slots.

**child.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>I'm a father now</h2>
    <grandchild :babies="babies">
      <template v-for="(baby, id) in babies" :slot="baby.name">
        <slot :name="baby.name"/>
      </template>
    </grandchild>
  </div>
</template>
```

**grandchild.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-for="(baby, id) in babies" :key="id">
      <span v-if="baby.isCry">Owe...owe...</span>
      <slot :name="baby.name">
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

**parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Come to grandpa</h2>
    <child :babies="myGrandChilds">
      <button slot="myGrandChilds[2].name">baby cry</button>
    </child>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to @DrSensor's answer.

In Vue3, you should use [dynamic slot name](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#dynamic-slot-names).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>I'm a father now</h2>
    <grandchild :babies="babies">
      <template v-for="(baby, id) in babies" #[baby.name]>
        <slot :name="baby.name"/>
      </template>
    </grandchild>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I think `:key` is missing, right?

Comment: @MoritzRingler true

Answer (score -1):

To translate several slots one level down conveniently to use the method described [at this link](https://gist.github.com/loilo/73c55ed04917ecf5d682ec70a2a1b8e2), and if you modify it a little, perhaps you will be able to transfer it deeper.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30542943)